# Power bi - Change a measure name based on selection from slicer

Tags: powerbi

I have a requirement where I need the column to change its title based on the slicer selection

Ex - My matrix grid has column called "ABCCases". I have 2 slicers which has values as shown below, One has years and other has CUR,AOP as slicer values

[image: Slicers]

The requirement is based on selection , my grid column ABCCases should show "2022CURCases". As you see 2022 and CUR strings are coming from selected values. Appreciate if someone can shed some light.

Tried with field parameter, but the DAX is not able to get the slicer value by using selectedvalue formula

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have both slicers as Dim tables you can create a measure as below and add it to the title of your visual under Title Text  Format Style - Field Value and on what field you need it to be based on the measure name in this scenario the below measure name.

```
_Title = SELECTEDVALUE(Year_Table[Year])& SELECTEDVALUE(Period_Table[Period])
```

[image]